# Disable click and darken background when menu is open (div)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a side menu that shows up when a button is clicked, it shows up after changing its width. Everything works fine, nonetheless, I want to make the whole body (excepts from the menu) look darken, and if possible to prevent clicks in anything but the menu. When the menu is closed, all should back to normality.

The second part of the JS is used to close the menu, when detects a click outside the menu, it works but I want to make it active only if menu is open, for example:

```
if(menuOpen)
  {
  $(document).mouseup(function(e)  
    {
    var container = $("mySidenav");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0)  
      {
      closeNav();
      }
    });
  }
```

```js
var menuOpen = false;

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myMenu").style.width = "50%";
  menuOpen = true;
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myMenu").style.width = "0%";
  menuOpen = false;
}

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $("mySidenav");

  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    closeNav();
  }
});
```

```css
#myMenu {
  height      : 100%;
  width       : 0;
  position    : fixed;
  z-index     : 1;
  top         : 0;
  right       : 0;
  background  : blue;
  overflow-x  : hidden;
  transition  : 0.5s;
  padding-top : 60px;
  display     : flex;
  align-items : center;
  opacity     : 0.98;
  z-index     : 9;
  color       : #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>This is just random information to make my point clear, don't take too much attention to it.</p>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="openNav()">Open Menu</a>
<p>Extra random Stuff</p>
<p>You can close the menu clicking elsewhere the page.</p>
<div id="myMenu">
  <ul>
    <li>This is menu stuff</li>
    <li>Menu Stuff 2</li>
    <li>Menu Stuff 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I can do this with JS code, but not with jQuery code ...

Comment: You are welcome Mister Jojo, nowadays jQuery is in disuse

Comment: I added my JS answer. alas you did not respond to my message until 2 hours later ... :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add overlay div and toggle it's display property when menu is opened - closed

```js
var menuOpen = false;
const menu = document.getElementById("myMenu")
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay')

function openNav() {
  menu.style.width = "50%";
  menuOpen = true;
  overlay.style.display = 'block'
}

function closeNav() {
  menu.style.width = "0%";
  overlay.style.display = 'none'
  menuOpen = false;
}

$('#myMenu').click(function(e) {
  closeNav();
  menuOpen = false;

});
```

```css
#myMenu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: blue;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0.98;
  z-index: 9;
  color: #fff;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is just random information to make my point clear, don't take too much attention to it.</p>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="openNav()">Open Menu</a>
<p>Extra random Stuff</p>
<p>You can close the menu clicking elsewhere the page.</p>
<div id="myMenu">
  <ul>
    <li>This is menu stuff</li>
    <li>Menu Stuff 2</li>
    <li>Menu Stuff 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="overlay">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I change to the #overlay div position: fixed; in order to move the overlay, when the scroll moves (otherwise, it will be rendered only at the top of the wepage and it will disappear when the user scrolls down). Before marked as answered I just want to clarify: the "menu" should close when the user press elsewhere outside the #myMenu (not in the ul selector)

Comment: I've just edited the answer

Comment: I'll marked as solved, nonetheless I meant "outside" the #myMenu: not #myMenu nor it's descendants.

Comment: I've closed my laptop. But you can add click event listener on overlay.. then call closeNav inside it

Comment: I took a different approach, but with the same results, thank you Kareem

Answer (score 1):

I will do that this way:

```js
const
  BtMenu      = document.querySelector('a.closebtn')
, myMenu      = document.querySelector('#myMenu')
, menuOpen = () => myMenu.classList.contains('open');
  ;

BtMenu.onclick = e => setMenuOpen(e, true);
myMenu.onclick = e => setMenuOpen(e, false);

// css  pointer-events : none;  doesn't work the same way!
document.querySelector('#overlay').onclick = e => e.stopPropagation();

function setMenuOpen(e, onOff)
  {
  e.preventDefault()
  myMenu.classList.toggle('open',onOff)

  if (e.target.matches('#myMenu li'))
    {
    console.log(`menu call : ${e.target.textContent }`)  
    setTimeout(console.clear, 2000)
    }
  }
  
// if ( menuOpen() ) { .... }
```

```css
#myMenu {
  --mOpen     : 60%;  /* or 50% as yours */
  height      : 100%;
  width       : 0;
  position    : fixed;
  top         : 0;
  right       : 0;
  background  : rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.98);
  overflow-x  : hidden;
  transition  : 0.5s ease-in-out;
  padding-top : 60px;
  display     : flex;
  align-items : center;
  color       : #fff;
  z-index     : 9;
  }
#myMenu > #overlay {
  position       : fixed;
  bottom         : 0;
  left           : 0;
  width          : 0;
  height         : 0;
  background     : rgba(31, 26, 61, 0.74);
  transition     : 0.5s ease-in-out;
  display        : block;
  }
#myMenu.open {
  width : var(--mOpen);
  }
#myMenu.open > #overlay {
  width  : calc( 100% - var(--mOpen) );
  height : 100%;
  }
#myMenu li:hover {
  cursor : pointer;
  color  : red; 
  }
  
/* for snippet console information */
.as-console-row { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<nav id="myMenu">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <ul>
    <li>This is menu stuff</li>
    <li>Menu Stuff 2</li>
    <li>Menu Stuff 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<p>This is just random information to make my point clear, don't take too much attention to it.</p>
<a href="" class="closebtn">Open Menu</a>


<p>Extra random Stuff</p>
<p>You can close the menu clicking elsewhere the page.</p>

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">link for testing when recovered </a>
```

Comment: It's a clever way to solve it, nonetheless, the #myMenu:before (that you use to darken the background) doesn't prevent the user to click links or select text in the background

Comment: @AlexandroGiles fixed... (css  `pointer-events : none;` was the wrong guy )